# How to reorder entries in a Perl Tk listbox using drag and drop?

Tags: perl, drag-and-drop, listbox, tk-toolkit, listboxitems

I have a scrollable listbox and I'd like to allow drag and drop to rearrange the order of entries. i.e. select a listbox entry and drag it to a different position in the same listbox.

Any working examples please?

Comment: [Check this](http://computer-programming-forum.com/33-perl/cca97818685975c1.htm)